# (batch) How to check for process priority?

Tags: batch-file

I can't find a way to check for a processes priority. I don't think tasklist could be the solution, but I don't know.  The program I'm searching for is vrad.exe and I would like an if output. Thanks

Comment: `wmic process get priority,name`. For Help `wmic /?`, `wmic process /?`, `wmic process get /?`. From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx *Scheduling priority of a process within an operating system. The higher the value, the higher priority a process receives. Priority values can range from 0 (zero), which is the lowest priority to 31, which is highest priority.*. A more specific example is `wmic process where "name='iexplore.exe'" get /format:list`

Comment: that works, but how would I set the output to a variable? or have the output be an if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `wmic process get` to get a process priority.

Use `for /f` to parse the output and setup a variable.

```
set "WMIC_CMD=wmic process where name^="process.exe" get /format:list ^| findstr Priority"

for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ('%WMIC_CMD%') do set PRIORITY=%%B

echo %PRIORITY%
```

Comment: that works, one more question, is it possible to set a priority with a number (ie 31) instead of setting with with a value like "high priority"

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/620724/changing-windows-process-priority-via-command-line

Comment: will this work even on "cmd.exe" from batch? ...batch that will start that cmd.exe?